# Product Distribution and Expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_d$ be $d$ independent Gaussian $N(0,1)$ random variables, and let $$Y=\frac{1}{\| X \|} (X_1, \ldots ,X_d)$$
Clearly $Y$ lies on the surface of the sphere $S^{d-1}$.

Let the vector $Z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be the projection of $Y$ onto its first $k$ coordinates, and let $L = \| Z \|^2$.

Clearly the expected squared length of $Z$ is $\mu = E[L] = \dfrac{k}{d}$.

Question:

(1) Why $E[L] = \dfrac{k}{d}$?

(2) Does any of the information above imply $X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \cdots + X_d^2=1$?

Remark: The above paragraph is obtained from this [paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/papers/jl.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PS:** For the moment I've struck out what I wrote below, **however** some trivial modifications should fix it.  You wrote ${}\in\mathbb R^k$. When I see the word "projection" I normally think of what I wrote below, and I believe that's how the word is most frequently used in linear algebra and geometry.

<s>Here is the projection:
$$
(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k,Y_{k+1},\ldots, Y_d) \mapsto (Y_1,\ldots,Y_k,0,\ldots, 0) = Z.
$$
Then we have
$$
Z^2 = Y_1^2+\cdots+Y_k^2 + \underbrace{0^2 + \cdots + 0^2}_\text{all 0s}.
$$
$$
\operatorname{E}(\|Z\|^2) = \operatorname{E}(Y_1^2)+\cdots+\operatorname{E}(Y_k^2) = k\operatorname{E}(Y_1^2). \tag 1
$$
And
$$
d\operatorname{E}(Y_1^2) = \operatorname{E}(Y_1^2)+\cdots+\operatorname{E}(Y_d^2) = \operatorname{E}(Y_1^2+\cdots+Y_d^2) = \operatorname{E}(1) = 1
$$
So $\operatorname{E}(Y_1^2) = \dfrac 1 d$, and so by $(1)$,
$$
\operatorname{E}(\|Z\|^2) = \frac k d.
$$</s>

Comment: So $Z^2$ is just square of each entry in the vector $Z$? Same as dot product?

Comment: I thought $Z = \frac{1}{\| X \|}(X_1,...,X_k)$?

Comment: @Idonknow : You have $$ Z = \big(\, \underbrace{Y_1,\ldots,Y_k}_{k \text{ components}}, \underbrace{0,\ldots\ldots,0}_{d-k\text{ components}}) =  \frac 1 {\|X\|} \big(\, \underbrace{ X_1,\ldots,X_k}_{k \text{ components}}, \underbrace{0, \ldots \ldots, 0}_{d-k \text{ components}} \big). $$

Comment: @Idonknow : Actually since you say ${}\in\mathbb R^k$, it would be $\displaystyle \frac 1 {\|X\|} (X_1,\ldots,X_k).$ That's not what I think of first when I see the word "projection".  But the word is sometimes used that way. $\qquad$